# Upload problem in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting this error:

> The upload destination folder does not appear to be writable.

But `is_dir` and `is_writable` both return true.

```
$config['upload_path'] = './work_order_doc/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size']= '100';
$config['max_width']  = '1024';
$config['max_height']  = '768';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$work_order_file="work_order_file";

var_dump(is_dir($config['upload_path']));
var_dump(is_writable($config['upload_path']));



if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($work_order_file))
   {
     $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
     print_r($error);
     $temp="";
     }
else
 {
   $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
   echo $temp=$upload_data['file_name'];
}
```

Comment: Did you change the access rights on the folder to 777 as the manual suggests?

Comment: yes. i have manually changed  access rights on the folder 777

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your host have blocked file uploads?
You can always try to specify full path to the upload directory.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP configuration may be not allowing you to get to the file/directory, try checking open_basedir in php.ini and make sure it is in allowed paths.